# Possible application of maximum modulus princple

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f,g$ are analytic on $\{ |z| \leq 1\}$ with $g \neq 0$ on $\{ |z| < 1\}$. Prove that $|f(z)| \leq |g(z)|$, $\forall z \in \{z = 1 \}$, implies $|f(0)| \leq |g(0)|$.

Here is my attempt:

By continuity of $f$ and $g$ we can find a radius $r$ such that $|f(z)| \leq |g(z)|$, $\forall z \in D - D_r(0)$, and so then by maximum modulus principle the maximum of $|f|$ is on the boundary of $D_r(0)$, say on $z_{max}$. But we have that $|g(z)| \geq |f(z_{max})|$ for all $z \in \partial D_r(0)$. How can I conclude that $g(0) \geq f(0)$ if all I know is the information on the boundary? Can I  just take the limit as $r \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Do you mean $|f(z)| \le |g(z)|$ for $|z| = 1$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: consider $f(z)/g(z)$....